# Cors error with ASP.NET Core web Api and Angular 10 on heroku

Tags: asp.net, heroku, webapi

I've been experiencing problem when trying to download file with HTTP GET from server

```
(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://pk-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com/api/download' from origin 'https://p-kochanowski.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Currently im hosting my backend on Heroku and frontend on Netlify App. The problem started occuring on server,  on local host there was no problem at all.

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
            options.AddPolicy("EnableCors", builder =>
                builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials()));

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors("EnableCors");

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
      "sslPort": 44309
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/emaildata",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      }
    },
    "PortfolioApp_Backend": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/emaildata",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://pk-portfolio-backend.herokuapp.com/"
    }
  }
}
```

**DownloadController**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[EnableCors("EnableCors")]
public class DownloadController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Download()
    {
        string fileName = "CV.pdf";
        string filePath = $"./assets/{fileName}";
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        return File(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream");

    }
}
```

I got a form that HTTP post's to the server, no problem at all with that request, the problem is with downloading file through http GET. Tried many combinations with Cors to work, with no success at all for now.

Comment: Hi @Kohan14, Have you found any solution for it. I am facing the same

Comment: That was a long time ago, but i think i've just screwed something up with cors rules, now i am programming frontend in vue/angular - so i forgot c# completly :D

Comment: Yes, I also made a silly mistake, resolved it after a break, any ways, thanks for responding